# Find and fill missing line up to nth line with text

Tags: bash, shell, centos

i need a bash script to find a text file in a folder (current level only) that has less than 10 line and add n/a to fill up to 10 line, while ignore txt file that has all 10 line.

i tried using 'find' to find txt file line, add to array then doing loop in the end i got headache (!^.^)

```
original
1. line
2. line
3. line
4. line

expected
1. line
2. line
3. line
4. line
5. n/a
..
10. n/a
```

tried with

```
array=( $(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' | xargs wc -l) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

limit=10
for f in ./*.txt; do
  total="$(wc -l <"$f")"
  ((total >= limit)) && {
    printf >&2 '%s has %d lines, skipping!\n' "$f" "$total" &&
    continue
  }
  while ((total++ < limit)); do
    printf '%d. n/a\n' "$total"
  done >> "$f"
done
```

Comment: i think i wrote my thanks few times already, dont know why it doesnt save. nvm, anyway thank you again. your solution work perfectrly for my case.